# Displaying an image on Javascript function call !

Tags: javascript, function, image

I am a javascript noob and I need help with this problem !

On a specific condition a function is called and when it is called , I want an image to be displayed ! How do I do that ? this is not working!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
document.write("<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />");
}

var r =true;
</script>
```

This is not working , I get this error

```
Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File: file:///C:/Users/Gowtham/Desktop/new%20%202.html
Line: 5, Column: 33
Source Code:
document.write("<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/sjs.png" />");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is that you're using double quotes for your `document.write` string literal, but you've also used a double quotes your HTML attributes:

```
document.write("<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />");
//                          ^--- here and other places
```

That double quote ends the string literal, so you get a syntax error. You'd want to escape that with a backslash, or use JavaScript's handy feature where you can use single quotes around string literals.

But that alone isn't going to solve the problem. If you call `document.write` after the main parsing of the page is finished, you're going to completely erase the page and *replace* it with new content.

To display an image after the main parsing of the page is complete, you create a new `img` element via the DOM `document.createElement` function and then append it to the element in which you want it to appear. For instance, this code puts a new image at the end of the document:

```
function addTheImage() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "http://....";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

To add to another element, rather than the end of `body`, you just need to get a reference to the element. There are various ways to do that, including `document.getElementById` to look it up by its `id` value, `document.getElementsByTagName` to look up all elements with a given tag, etc. Some browsers offer very rich methods like `querySelectorAll` that let you use CSS selectors, but not all do yet. (Many JavaScript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) plug that gap for you, though, and offer other handy utility features, and features smoothing over browser inconsistencies and outright browser bugs.)

More about the dom:

- The [DOM2 Core specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) (widely supported by major browsers)
- The [DOM2 HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) (DOM stuff specific to HTML, also fairly widely supported)
- The [DOM3 Core specificiation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) (less widely supported, but things are improving)

Comment: I did know about document.createElement but it is a big task and I want the image in a particular postion only . That's for advanced guys not for noobs :)

Comment: You should start learning JavaScript. createElement thing is commonly used when generating contents in page using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Escape your document.write codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
document.write("<img border=\"0\" src=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some%20image.png\" />");
}

var r =true;
</script>
```

Comment: it depends what other codes you have. This code piece will not clear your page & the function is not called as well.

Comment: actually the document.write is nested !

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function _enabled() {
    document.write("<img border='0' src='http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-    C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png' />");
   }

  var r =true;
</script>
```

Note: Single quotes.

Tested works fine.

Comment: Note the double quote near "border" :-)

Comment: @cypher yes.. @Hack tested in chrome latest,FF4 , works smoothly

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your quote marks, or use single quote marks inside the string passed to `document.write`. For example `"<img border=\"0\"...` or `<img border='0'...`

At the moment, your string ends at the start of your first attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to escape quotes or use single quotes for javascript and double for html (for example).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function _enabled() {
        document.write('<img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-C4vvMEB9MyI/TfW0lduV2NI/AAAAAAAAAZc/N7HL1pUusGw/s1600/some image.png" />');
    }

    var r =true;
</script>
```